# How to specify dependencies with "foo_msgs" catkin packages

Tags: ros, catkin, messages, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say I have two catkin packages, `foo` and `foo_msgs`, in my workspace.  Here's how I currently have them set up:

```
project(foo_msgs)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS message_generation)
add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY msg
  FILES foomsg.msg
)
generate_messages()
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)
```

```
project(foo)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS foo_msgs)
catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
```

I find that if I `catkin_make foo`, the message isn't generated.  Indeed, `catkin_make foo_msgs` is a no-op.  `catkin_make foo_msgs_gencpp` works, however.  In order to get `foo` to build correctly, I must add the following line to its `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_dependencies(foo foo_msgs_gencpp)
```

Is this by design?  I'd expect that building the package `foo_msgs` would automatically generate all its messages.  Is there a way to make that happen?

**Edit:** I've approved WilliamWoodall's answer, although KruseT's was just as useful.  (I also added the `include_directories()` line to `foo`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, which I initially forgot.)

It turns out my solution is correct; the `foo_msgs_gencpp` auto-target should be added as a dependency of the `foo` target.  Note that there is some disagreement about whether a different solution should be supported by catkin; KruseT started a discussion on the topic [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ros-sig-buildsystem/dvVO5QCHBLM/discussion).

Since this type of explicit dependency auto-target (`_gencpp` and `_genpy`) is necessary for using ROS messages/actions/services in any executable, library, or script, I think it should be better documented (I found no reference to it in [catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild)).  KruseT opened a related rosdistro issue [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/439).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-%22foo_msgs%22-catkin-packages/) by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 462 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your projects are setup correctly (mostly), you just need to run `catkin_make` with no arguments.

First update `foo`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(foo)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS foo_msgs)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(foo_node src/foo_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(foo_node foo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Using `add_dependencies(...)` is by design or necessity, however you look at it, because we cannot know or assume that `foo`'s targets (executables or libraries) use and therefore depend on the messages which are getting generated by `foo_msgs`.

Then just execute `catkin_make` with no arguments.

If you want to build `foo_msgs` explicitly (not the whole workspace) then as of pull request [ros/catkin#352](https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/352) you can do `catkin_make --pkg foo_msgs`.

Calling `catkin_make foo_msgs` is not sufficient because that is instructing `catkin_make` to invoke the `foo_msgs` make target which does not exist. tkruse's solution simply adds a `foo_msgs` target which depends on the `foo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp` target, allowing it to be callable and causing the `foo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp` target to be generated. This is not something we do by default because packages often define targets with the same name as the project which would immediately cause a conflict.

The only reliable way to build an entire package (including all of its targets) is to go to the package's build space and invoke `make [all]`, which is what `catkin_make --pkg` does.

I setup an example repository here:

https://github.com/wjwwood/catkin_demos/tree/ros_answers_52744

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-06**:
Hi WilliamWoodall, this is very helpful!  Clearly the _gencpp dependency needs to go somewhere explicitly.  You list it in foo's CMakeLists file.  In that case, if foo_msgs is already installed (so catkin is only building foo), will the foo_msgs_gencpp dependency be correctly resolved by catkin?

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-06**:
Yes, CMake will ignore targets which are not defined, you could add `add_dependencies(foo_node bar_does_not_exist)` and it will build with no warnings.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-06**:
Great!  This is my favorite solution, since it doesn't introduce new targets (foo_msgs), and explicitly encodes the dependency between the foo (binary) target and the generated cpp messages.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-06**:
Also, I want to stress about catkin_make arguments: (a) sometimes it is useful to build only particular targets (yes, targets, not packages), and (b) running catkin_make with no arguments doesn't help here; the _gencpp target is still required to ensure targets are built in the correct order.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-02-06**:
(a) building specific target is already supported by "catkin_make", any argument without a special meaning is passed straight forward to "make", see "catkin_make --help" for details.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-07**:
Hi Dirk!  I understand this, I just wanted to correct the answer.  I believe that WilliamWoodall's assertion that "running catkin_make with no arguments" would somehow fix my problem is incorrect.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-25**:
It looks like the version of CMake on Ubuntu Xenial and newer now complains of non-existent targets. Switching to `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}` seems to make it more happy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make with an argument just passes that argument to make. That a make target for the package exists is more by chance than design, I'd guess it is added by cmake for each subfolder (but not with nested folders). Maybe you can open a ticket on github to add the feature of a dedicated target to make. However a small problem exists, frequently a package named foo defines an executable named foo, so the target names overlap each other. Not sure whether any clean solution is possible. At least it wont be straightforward.

What you can do to cause "make foo_msgs" not be a noop is in package foo_msg, add a dependency like this:

```
add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME} DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp)
```

which is equivalent to

```
# add_custom_target(foo_msgs DEPENDS foo_msgs_gencpp)
```

but easier for copy&paste

[Update3: this is wrong:

Update: add_dependencies is definitely the wrong way to go, the way you use it (in foo, add dependency to foomsg). add_dependency should never cross catkin project boundaries. For you it only works coincidentally (because catkin cheats cmake conventions), it will break build in other cases or when building the projects in isolation.]

Update3: So it seems that indeed currently, calling add_dependencies accross package boundaries it currently the only recommendable way to achieve that the headers generated by foo_msg exist before they are being consumed by a target in foo.

We'll discuss this in the buildsystem SIG and maybe there will be a cleaner solution in the future.Discussion here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ros-sig-buildsystem/dvVO5QCHBLM/discussion

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-01-18**:
Ok, so the add_dependencies(foo foo_msgs_gencpp) solution is the right way to go?

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-05**:
Apologies kruset, I'm still confused.  What exactly should I add to my CMakeLists file(s) for this example?  I haven't found anything but the _gencpp dependency (across catkin project boundaries) to work.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-06**:
There is no reason to call `catkin_make` with arguments... You are not telling catkin_make what packages you want to build you are just passing targets to make, and the project target and executable/library targets can overlap.  It is better to just invoke `catkin_make` with no arguments.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-06**:
I partially agree and partiall disagree, WilliamWoodall.  Yes, clearly the user of catkin should be aware that catkin_make targets correspond directly with executable/library targets.  I've found it very useful to only make/remake particular targets during development for compilation time purposes.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-06**:
kruset, thanks for the clarification; this appears to be the best solution I've found.  Perhaps it should go in a tutorial?  Setting up this type of package structure (foo and foo_msgs) seems to be a very standard practice, and that I had such a hard time getting it to work properly is unfortunate.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-06**:
The reason `caktin_make foo_msgs` is a no-op is that there is no make target for a package by default. In stead there is a Makefile for each time `project(...)` is called in CMake.  The correct thing to do in order to build a package is to go to its location in the build folder and invoke make.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-06**:
In my example, if I run: `cd build/catkin_demos/foo_msgs && make` all of the messages are generated. This is basically what `catkin_make --pkg foo_msgs` will do: https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/352

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-06**:
Regarding documentation, I opened https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/439.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-06**:
Thanks to both of you, I now understand.

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-02-07**:
Thanks for the third update KruseT!  And thanks for the pointer to the google groups discussion. I'll add it to the question.

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-08-16**:
@KruseT: Could you please add the source why not to use `add_dependencies` for interweaving projects/packages. I like the idea to stick to cmake conventions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the modern way of doing this is to add a dependency on `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}`, as specified on [this documentation page](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/cpp_msg_dependencies.html). It should look something like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS foo_msgs)

add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(your_library ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

Originally posted by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) with karma: 529 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-28**:
You should check that `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}` is set to something before passing it to `add_dependencies(...)`.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-28**:
https://gist.github.com/wjwwood-snippets/5979727

**Comment by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) on 2013-08-28**:
Doesn't the fix for this issue make this check redundant? https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/453

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-28**:
Ah yes, I forgot we added that.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-07**:
The documentation link above is broken. The page can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/cpp_msg_dependencies.html).